# Set Min/Max of Spin Button Form Control with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spin button on my worksheet (not in a userform), and I need to set the minimum and maximum values in VBA. Easy, right? I tried `worksheetName.Shapes("shapeName").Min = x` but I get Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

I used Excel's macro recorder and changed the min and max of the spin button, and it recorded the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("shapeName").Select
With Selection
    .Min = x
    .Max = y
End With
```

How is it that if I select the shape, I can then access its properties, but if I reference the shape directly I am unable to access the same properties? This does not make sense to me. Obviously, I would like to avoid selecting the shape and referencing "selection," as this generally is not best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Shape.ControlFormat` property:

```
Sub test()

Dim shp As Excel.Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Spinner 1")
With shp.ControlFormat
    .Min = 2
    .Max = 33
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @DavidZemens, thanks, yeah I always have to poke around before I remember that one.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be helpful, although not particularly intuitive...

[Excel-VBA: Getting the values from Form Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219769/excel-vba-getting-the-values-from-form-controls)

As I mention in the comments above, it is peculiar. The SpinButton is a member of the worksheet's `Shapes` collection, but it does not allow you to access those properties as a shape directly (see Doug's answer for how to do this another way which is probably better).

Try:

```
With ActiveSheet.Spinners("spinbutton1")
    .Min = x
    .Max = y
End With
```

Likewise, you can delcare a variable and iterate if you have multiple controls like this:

```
Dim spinbtn as Spinner 'or As Variant
For each spinbtn in ActiveSheet.Spinners
    spinbtn.Min = x
    spinbtn.Max = y
Next
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
    TextBox3.Text = val(TextBox3.Text) - 1
    If TextBox3.Text < 0 Then TextBox3.Text = 0
End Sub
```