# Retrieve selected option from combobox(form control) excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Hey I don't seem to understand why my code isn't working as I saw this as an answer to another question in SO. I want to retrieve the selected item from the combobox, as I subsequently have to use it in a match index function. Here is my code

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Sheets

Sub test2()
Set ws = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
 With ws(1).Shapes("Drop Down 2").ControlFormat

  .List(.ControlFormat.ListIndex) = ws(1).Range("I8").Value

 End With
End Sub
```

Also, I wanted to know about how to refer to dropdowns in general? Because I have 10 such comboboxes(dropdowns) each named differently on a numerical basis. So, instead of referring to a specific dropdown like "Drop Down 2" or through using a loop say ("Drop Down " & i), is there a generic way to refer to dropdowns on a particular sheet? I really need help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you retrieve the selected item value:

```
Dim myindex As Long, myitem As String
Dim ws As Worksheet 

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'~~> Currently selected item index at runtime
myindex = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.Value
'~~> Currently selected item value at runtime
myitem = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.List(myindex)
```

For your second question, you can use the *Shape Collection Object*.
Then use *For Each* loop construct.

```
Dim shp As Shape, ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim myindex As Long, myitem As String

'~~> Iterate the shapes collection object
For Each shp In ws.Shapes
    '~~> Check the type
    If shp.Type = msoFormControl Then
        myindex = shp.ControlFormat.Value
        myitem = shp.ControlFormat.List(myindex)
        '~~> additional codes here
    End If
Next
```

But if you need to do specific stuff in specific *ComboBoxes*, use what you described in your question. HTH

**Edit1:**

```
For Each shp In ws.Shapes
    '~~> Check the type
    If shp.Type = msoFormControl Then
        With shp.ControlFormat
            myvalue = .List(.ListIndex)
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Above works as well as you commented.
As to why it works only under *With Clause* is because that is basically why you use *With*.
To somehow shorten the code. If you want to do it without *With*, use below:

```
myvalue = shp.ControlFormat.List(shp.ControlFormat.ListIndex)
```

Comment: Hey thank you it works :) And I tried using the .list(.listindex) property, it worked as well but only when nested under the "With" command..any idea why ?

Comment: FYI, the worksheet has a DropDowns collection you can use rather than going all round the houses testing shape types. ;)

Comment: @dhruva_04 Rory is right. You can try it as well as discussed [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219769/excel-vba-getting-the-values-from-form-controls)

Comment: Yeah this was the question I referred to before coming up with my query. So how will that go ? For Each shp In ws.dropdowns ? I am sorry but I am still new to VBA :/