# runtime error 424 excel vba by just trying to insert values

Tags: excel, vba

Why is it giving me a `Runtime Error '424'` when I'm just simply trying to insert values? Is there something wrong? I swear this one worked on ActiveX Button, but not on Form Button that I used Macro to work with:

Module1:

```
Sub Macro1()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
Sheet1.Range("D2").Value = valtextbox1.Value
Sheet1.Range("C2").Value = valtextbox2.Value
Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = valtextbox3.Value
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top.

Comment: but it returns "variable not defined" with `Sub Macro1()` highlighted. I didn't even assign any variables :,(

Comment: And when `Sub Macro1()` is highlighted, what else is highlighted?

Comment: That's all it is highlighted

Comment: Are you [sure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IiMb.png)?

Comment: Where are `valtextbox1`, `valtextbox2`, etc. located?

Comment: @GSerg the error shown in the image is like that.

Comment: @norie the valtextbox1, valtextbox2, and others were ActiveX textboxes and comboboxes. I was trying to get those values

Comment: @Dunnodotcom Well, on that image `Sub Macro1()` is highlighted, and so is `valtextbox1`.

Comment: If you want to refer to ActiveX controls on a worksheet directly the code would need to be in the relevant worksheet module, is it?

Comment: @ GSerg oof, i think i didnt notice about that lol. The image you show to me was also like that

Comment: @norie I did, but when I also used ActiveX Button, in that the same sheet, that I used to put code in, they were not getting values from the ActiveX textboxes and comboboxes values properly. Somebody recommended me to use Form controls instead of ActiveX controls because ActiveX controls were known to have many strange issues

Comment: nvm, i solved the issue now.

Comment: @Dunnodotcom That's fine, but surely you should then have changed the way you are [referring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4219769/11683) to these Form controls, because they are a completely different thing that does not have a first class representation in codenames.

Comment: @Gserg I see. Thx for your advice :) PS: I'm still a vba beginner. I started probably few months ago